# How do I bypass my viewdidload void?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am making a tic tac toe sort of game and I want the user to be able to go the menu in the middle of a game, but be able to come back without the app using the -(void)viewdidload, which would reset the game. How would I do that?

Comment: Please include some code from viewDidLoad. You can't stop the method being called (unless you stop the view being unloaded in the first place). It's likely that your solution is going to be to rearrange how you store and restore state in your view controller rather than just bypassing a method.

Comment: This is a *very* open-ended question, and there are a multitude of ways to achieve what you want. But from the way the question is phrased, I get the impression that you are relatively new to programming in Objective-C. If so, I would strongly suggest getting a good beginners' book on the topic (maybe the Big Nerd Ranch guide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is basically keep your previous state of the game when the user goes to menu.

And then on your  -(void)viewdidload return to that last state by implementing your own logic.